# TWRP installation problems

Tags: stock-android, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have rooted my SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE 2 GT-N7100 Android Version Kitkat 4.4.2.   I wanted to install nandroid backup manager for that I need TWRP  to be installed. I lost my SIM network after installing TWRP. That's probably  because of unsupported version of  TWRP

Can anyone mention  steps for installing TWRP?

Answer (score 2):

[TWRP for Samsung Galaxy Note 2 N7100](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote2n7100.html) has the official version of TWRP for your device. It also lists out installation steps using

- App
- Odin
- `dd` method

This you tube link is also helpful http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=a7z8W6b2CrQ

**Flashing Stock**

I would suggest you go the odin way. Fool proof way is to first flash stock and then TWRP, since you have a SIM issue. Flashing stock should fix that. Flashing TWRP in the present state *may/ may not* help in getting your SIM recognised, so it is advisable to flash stock first, check SIM is working and then flash TWRP (of course after backing up data)

If you don't have stock with you, you can download from [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/) after registering. Make sure you download ROM of the region you stay in.

Odin has different versions and some of the versions have options changed. Hence, the description in guides may differ with options available on the tool. This guide has a good pictorial description corresponding to newer version of Odin

http://androidmtk.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin

Here is one more link (also having stock ROMs) from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1424997)

Comment: but i had slready installed my kitkat after flashing i dont want to formaf again is thete any another way without any data loss.

Comment: 1. It is always better to do it the right way 2. You can instal TWRP by Odin as explained but what is the guarantee that SIM Will be restored? You can always try this and if you are lucky, things will be fine and SIM restored.3.my last two devices were same as yours and was able to overcome multiple problems by first flashing stock ROM bringing system to original state first 4.TWRP also best way is through Odin

Comment: Please share your outcome for benefit of others. And if you think this solution meets your question, you can consider"accepting", so that others also see value in it. No obligation, your choice